# Getting zapped by computer (not exactly but yes)

Tags: pc, power-supply, power, cable

I am getting current on the screws and metal portions of my computer for some reason and it only happens when i am standing on the ground and using the tester or getting zapped by it on the softer side of my hand, i.e., upper skin portion. So, i tried checking all kind of ports. Try draining the PC of extra charge etc. Doesn't work.

But, i found out that the PC is not the problem but my Power port or the Power cable may be.
So, Below is the spec and images of my power cable.

it is a `i sheng sp 62 bs1363/a 13amps fused` cable rated 13A, 250V on head of the cable and 10A, 250V on the output pin.

[image: i sheng sp 62 bs1363/a 13amps fused[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5A9P.jpg)

So, i checked it on every power ports/sockets i have. The power sockets i have in my home is rated 20 & 10 A, 240V ( This cable only fits on that kind of port only ). They are fine like Live is having current, Earth and Neutral have no current but when i plug this PSU cable into the port i found that a small current is passing through the Earth port of the output pin of the power cable. But, tester only detects it when i am on the ground or touched to some walls etc.

I am afraid of putting my PC on this cable. Please help.

P.S. : I live in India. So, any cable that suit the wiring would be nice to know. Also, this is a UK cable i got because of the cooler master platinum PSU i guess. They don't make Indian version of it.

Let me reinstate the problem in bullet points. It may be clearer.

1. The power ports of my home is showing no sign of any current other than on the Live.
2. When i plug in the PSU cable to the power port, It's showing current on Earth of the PSU output head but only when i am standing on ground or touching anything grounded.
3. I have a inverter which supply power to my house in case of brown outs It is a 1450VA inverter quite enough to run my PC too. But, for test purposes i remove the inverter supply from the main power supply of home and attach the PSU cable to the output of inverter. Weirdly, PSU cable show no such behavior as mentioned in the 2nd point.
4. So, I guess there is something wrong with the mains but 1st point doesn't show any such sign.

I am just going crazy because can't figure out which is the trouble.

Comment: I'm closing this, because it's not something we deal with here, but I cannot in good faith allow you to leave without a safety warning: what others have said here is right. If you're getting shocks off the case, something is seriously wrong - **do not use any of the equipment until you've verified everything is safe**. If you can't do that, call someone who can, like an electrician.

Comment: The other thing to note is that if you're buying a UK three-pin cable, **make sure it has a CE mark or BS kitemark** - those markings indicate that the cable has passed European or British safety standards, respectively, and is therefore safe to use. I don't see those marks anywhere on the cable in your picture, and I don't recognise the brand - I wouldn't trust that cable with an LED, let alone mains power. Use recognised equipment or don't use any.

Comment: @ArtOfCode Sorry didn't know that. I thought it is related to hardware. So, i asked here. Hey Mod!, can you transfer this question to super user though?! I don't know what others will answer. I somewhat solved it for now by simply and literally earthing the the earth of my plug and socket by hammer and nail  and a 3 ft long wire right on the wall . It's a LOL type solution but i guess it is working. So far no zapping or current flow in to the system. :) But, i would love to hear any other solution rather than hanging a wire over my head. So, can you please transfer it to super user?!

Comment: I don't know if Super User will take it, but I'll ask one of their moderators.

Comment: @ArtOfCode Thanks. I checked my cable. There is no BS kite or CE mark. It has a mark saying approved by ASTA though. Don't know what is that. [This Mark](https://d2z8ufzpcqvblm.cloudfront.net/sites/www.voltimum.co.uk/files/styles/image_630/public/fields/main_image/gb/others/V/2006101249415062TAdiamondnotextBW.jpg)

Comment: I don't recognise that mark. It _might_ be reliable, but I don't know. If it's a UK three-pin, it should be approved by UK standards - either CE or BS.

Comment: Are you sure that it’s the computer and not you? Most of your story sounds like you are getting electrostatically charged. Also, what exactly means *zapped* here?

Comment: https://www.intertek.com/marks/asta/diamond/ explains the source of the ASTA certification mark. "The ASTA Diamond Mark is one of the few certification marks that the United Kingdom (UK) authorities accept for 3-pin plugs. UK law requires that 3-pin plugs be certified against BS1363 by an accredited certification body like Intertek. The ASTA Diamond Mark fulfils the mandatory requirements for the approval of 3-pin plugs to BS1363 for sale in the UK and over 40 other countries."

Comment: @Wrzlprmft No i am not electrostatically charged because i don't wear sandals in home plus i use that earthing thing wrapped to hand when working with PC. Anyways, i solved the problem actually double problem. Thanks though for feedbacks

Comment: @K7AAY @ArtOfCode Thank you very much fellas. I solved the problem. It was a double whammy. One by the so called qualified electrician and other by the cable company itself. The wire of my monitor was actually faulty. It's an `isheng` too but as per UK recommendation Brown : Live , BLue: Neutral and Yellow-green : Earth. The switched the brown and blue wire lol. This whole time my monitor is getting jammed and rammed like anything. I am gonna file a complain with Samsung. Anyways, i cut off the head and put a equal volt and amp Indian style ISI marked plug. The other problem is .....

Comment: The electrician is just a dumba** . Most of them in my country are. Sadly. Don't know about the home wiring ( as i am in a rented house, I informed the owner though ). Anyways, I took the light bulb test for earth and live and neutral and live for every socket. All but one are faulty, where my inverter is connected. So, basically i connected there. It's fine now. I have to switch my room and table though. Learned some good lesson during this entire session. ...

Comment: Lessons: 1. If you have perseverance and keep on digging things; you will land on the right solution no matter how hard it is. 2. Community is a great thing and great resource of knowledge. Thank to you guys. 3. Company like Samsung can make faulty Plug heads too for their expensive monitors lol. 4. Electricians in my country are lame and rude too as if they know everything and won't let you tell him what has happened. Not all of them but most of them.

Comment: @K7AAY [Here is the first culprit](https://ibb.co/hXYrWm7) . Can't show the photo of the second culprit (electrician) though. :P sorry about that.